# parse csv in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, csv, ios6

I have tried this method to parse csv and I am getting the value but If any field is in double quotes "" and has a comma within like "45,34,555" then its seperaing the value in 3 fields its just one field .How should I modify the below code to get the required result.

```
 NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"csv"];


    NSError*  error;
    NSString* Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];


    if (Data)
    {
        NSArray *myText = [Data componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSInteger idx;
        for (idx = 0; idx < myText.count; idx++) {
            NSString *data =[myText objectAtIndex:idx];
            NSLog(@"%@", data);
            id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0+idx*0.002777778];
            id y = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:data];
            [contentArray addObject:
             [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y",nil]];
        }
        self.dataForPlot = contentArray;

    }
```

Comment: CVS format is a lot more complex than most people realize. Values containing the field delimiter must be in quotes. Values with quotes must be properly escaped. Values with newlines must be in quotes and span multiple lines. You can't use simple string splitting to parse general CSV data. Try something like https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser (note - I've never used it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into NSScanner for this purpose. You need to detect if you are getting double quotes, if yes, then you scan until the closing quotes and treat this as a single unit. If you get a colon then you know that you got the next column.

Comment: you don't. either you write your own CSV parser or use the one that rmaddy recommended. Dave DeLong is awesome and so is probably his CSV parser.

Comment: I tried that but i am getting an error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883020/chcsvparser-unable-to-implement-in-the-project-getting-error